# audio jack ground weirdness

Tags: amplifier

[image]

Above is my circuit. If the audio jack's (from my mobile phone) ground is not connected to the circuit's ground, the circuit itself functions normal (the collector emitter voltage is around 12 volts, everything is in good condition) but when i now connect the audio jack's ground to the ground of the circuit and i connect the jack to my mobile phone, the collector emitter voltage becomes around 24 volts, without any music playing.. What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is no other connection to the mobile phone (it's not grounded somehow to the power supply of this circuit, for example), then it looks like C2 isn't really acting like a capacitor and is somehow passing DC.  This could be because it is a bad part, installed backwards, or you didn't wait long enough for it to charge up.

1 mF is a very large value for coupling audio into this circuit.  The input impedance of this circuit is about 1.5 kΩ.  Even if this is supposed to be "Hi-Fi" audio and you therefore set the high pass rolloff at around 10 Hz, that would still only require about 10 µF capacitance.  You have two orders of magnitude more than that, which will cause this circuit to take a while to settle when a change in input DC level occurs.

It is also troubling that you show this 1 mF capacitor as being unpolarized and without a voltage rating.  Almost certainly it is electrolytic, which is polarized and must be installed the right way around.  If you installed it backwards, then it will leak excessively causing the symptom you see, and it will be damaged.  The negative side should go to the input and the positive side to the base of the transistor.  The maximum voltage spec of capacitors must always be kept in mind too.

Replace C2 with a 10 µF ceramic with maybe 20 V tolerance.  That should still pass bass well enough, but won't leak, and the polarity won't matter.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the transistor burned out about the same time you hooked up the ground. A [2N3904](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2N3904) isn't going to tolerate dissipating 1.5W (130 mA × 12 V) for very long at all.

Comment: 2n3904 is famous,, what else do you recommend, i have tip41 here but i think its not suitable for small signal scales.. what u thnk sir dave

Comment: Look, I'm going to be brutally honest here: I'm not actually interested in helping you solve this problem. You've already asked a long series of questions that are all about this same application, and it's becoming clear that you're not learning anything from all the answers you've received so far. Furthermore, these questions add nothing to the value of the site for other users. You need to get a good book on transistor amplifier design and *study it thoroughly*. In the meantime, go buy yourself a set of powered speakers for your phone. There are literally thousands of them on the market.

Comment: ok sorry. ok im gonna get a book and study it thorughly during my free time. thanks dave

Comment: I concur.  He is not aware of his base current and unaware of 1mF cap polarity risks (pop!) of high reverse bias to these very low voltage caps. The design is not good for audio fidelity and the 470uF unloaded with a DMM will have a 4700 second time constant.(if 10Mohm), so honestly ~@wave, what are you trying to do?